# Is there any function for reading NFC-A (ISO14443A) tag with X-NUCLEO_NFC05A1?

Tags: c, nfc, stm32, rfid, nucleo

I'm using X-NUCLEO-NFC05A1 with STM32 NUCLEO-F401RE board to read an NFC-A (ISO14443A) tag. I couldn't find any function for reading the tag. Can anyone help me?

I tried the [sample given by ST](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/ecosystems/stm32-open-development-environment/stm32-nucleo-expansion-boards/stm32-ode-connect-hw/x-nucleo-nfc05a1.html#tools-software), I could find write function from there. But I couldn't find any reading function from there.

Comment: Maybe you need to write  one yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `rfalTransceiveBlockingTxRx()` from `rfal_rf.h` provided by the RFAL library. That transceive mechanism applies to all RF technologies.

Since there is no generic commandset for interacting with NFC-A tags, the exact coding of the READ command will depend on your specific tag type. For instance, for a Type 2 tag, the READ command would consist of two bytes: `0x30 <BLOCK-ADDRESS-AS-SINGLE-BYTE>`

For such a tag, you could, for instance, use something like this:

```
uint8_t bufferTx[2];
uint16_t lenTx;
uint8_t bufferRx[16];
uint16_t lenRxMax, lenRx;
ReturnCode status;

lenTx = 0;
bufferTx[lenTx++] = 0x30;
bufferTx[lenTx++] = 0;  // TODO: change this to the read offset

lenRxMax = 16;
lenRx = 0;
status = rfalTransceiveBlockingTxRx(&bufferTx[0], lenTx, &bufferRx[0], lenRxMax, &lenRx, RFAL_TXRX_FLAGS_DEFAULT, rfalConvMsTo1fc(5));

// if status does not indicate error,
// you will now find the response in bufferRx,
// the actual response length is lenRx
```

Comment: First of all, I'm a beginner for these subjects (nfc/nfc tags). I'm using a NFC-A T2T device and I could found the uid/nfc id with rfalNfcaListenDevice.nfcId1. Now I want to read the content of it. What do you mean by 'read offset'? What I want to set for bufferTx[lenTx++] in my case?

Comment: I would suggest that you start by reading a book about NFC to get a feeling for the protocols (e.g. [Rankl & Effing](https://www.wiley.com/en-at/Smart+Card+Handbook%2C+4th+Edition-p-9780470743676), though the German version is certainly much better). Since you already seem to know that your tag is a T2T, you could also start by getting a copy of the NFC Forum Type 2 Tag specification (or the older NFC Forum Type 2 Tag Operation specification). It lists all the commands that you need and it also shows you how data on those tags is organized (linear memory layout, hence the read offset).

Comment: If you know the exact product type (e.g. NXP NTAG2xx), you might also want to grab a copy of the datasheet for that tag from the manufacturer. The datasheet will also tell you the format and coding of commands, responses, and the exact memory layout.

Comment: Btw. read offset is the block address of the block that you want to read from the tag (or actually the first of 4 blocks that you will read from the tag).